# Concat dataframes using rows from second dataframe which don't exist in first dataframe based on subset of columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have 2 large dataframes as follows:

df1

```
C1  C2  C3  V1
a   e   k   1
b   f   j   2
d   g   h   3
```

df2

```
C1  C2  C3  V1
a   e   m   21
d   g   p   1
e   f   q   2
f   g   r   3
```

I want to get the following:

```
C1  C2  C3  V1
a   e   k   1
b   f   j   2
d   g   h   3
e   f   q   2
f   g   r   3
```

Where I have only included rows from `df2` where C1 and C2 are not present in `df1`. i.e. I dropped first row of `df2` as `a, e` was already present in `df1`.

I am trying:

```
df1['id'] = df1[['C1', 'C2']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
df2['id'] = df2[['C1', 'C2']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)
df3 = df2[~df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]
pd.concat([df1, df3])
```

Is there a better way to do this using some inbuilt function as I run into this kind of situation a lot with varying number of columns.

Comment: You probably want to set ['C1','C2'] to be your index, (actually a multiindex). Then see [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append df2 to df1 and drop duplicates

```
new=df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates(subset=['C1','C2'],keep='first')
```

print(new)

```
 C1 C2 C3  V1
0  a  e  k   1
1  b  f  j   2
2  d  g  h   3
3  e  f  q   2
4  f  g  r   3
```

Comment: you're missing a few rows ;) Also this would imply that the index is the same in both dataframes

Comment: in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71767232/1) (incorrect) answer :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
(df1
 .set_index(['C1', 'C2'])
 .combine_first(df2.set_index(['C1', 'C2']))
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  C1 C2 C3  V1
0  a  e  k   1
1  b  f  j   2
2  d  g  h   3
3  e  f  q   2
4  f  g  r   3
```

###### using merge

This is a bit more complex, you need to perform a negative merge with help of `indicator=True`:

```
cols = ['C1', 'C2']
df2_only = (df1[cols]
            .merge(df2, on=cols, indicator=True, how='right')
            .query('_merge == "right_only"').drop(columns='_merge')
           )

out = pd.concat([df1, df2_only])
```